# Having outlook automatically forward emails then delete the message in the sent folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to get outlook to automatically forward emails to my personal account, leave them in the inbox, but at the same time not fill up my sent box. I can't find a way to make it forward but not stick a sent message in my sent messages. I tired to make two rules, one to forward and one to delete, but the rules to apply on one's sent messages don't include a delete option.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Version of Outlook and Exchange would be useful...

Comment: It's Outlook 07. Not sure about Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Un-check the box for "Save copies of messages in Sent Items folder"

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 07 you can specify both the delete and forward rule as shown in the picture below. Set the rule up as "Check message when they arrive" for testing purposes I choose "only to me" then checked forward to my Gmail and the delete option. I then sent and email directly to me from my gmail and it forwarded the message back to my Gmail and deleted it, I do not see anything in the sent folder either. So this should work if you have 07, again it would help if you specified a version.

[image]

Comment: But by doing this don't the messages get deleted from the Inbox in outlook?

Comment: I tired it, they do. I'd like the messages to stay in my outlook inbox, but not in my outlook sent messages.

Comment: @COB try the top option for moving to inbox as well. so it will:forward it, move it to your inbox, and delete it.

Comment: You can also add yourself to the forward list then add an exception on the next page to not apply this rule for emails from you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using POP or IMAP to import your mail into your personal account directly from the mail server?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a VBscript for this to work.  Outlook won't delete copies of email on send.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013, go to File > Options > Mail

Under save messages, uncheck the two boxes:

- Save forwarded messages
- Save copies of messages in the Sent Items folder

[image: Save copies]